# I want to add another top level menu item to Umbraco

Tags: menu, umbraco

Running latest build,
Added Business Site starter kit and nForum with Friendly Ghost Skin.

I simply want to add a link to the top level nav for the forum... but Umbraco is challenging..
ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not worked with the starter kits but, correct me if I'm wrong, the top nav links are the ones below the "Business Site"-folder.

[image: Node Tree]

What you need to do is to create a new node in that folder and they will appear in the top nav.

Comment: Thx! I needed exactly that.